# what can Phing do that Ant can't?

Tags: php, ant, phing

I'm doing PHP development and I'm thinking of using one of these. I have both PHP and Java installed on my machine. In theory I could use any of the two.

What are the compelling arguments to pick Phing over Ant?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The greatest argument I have in favor of Phing is that it's fully **developed in PHP** ; which means, at least :

- You can debug it / submit patches if you want
- You can **develop tasks in PHP**

  - including tasks which are specific to your project
  - that can use stuff from your project *(I've written a couple of tasks that use functions of Drupal, in a drupal-based project)*
  - And, if you are working on a PHP project, your team probably knows PHP well -- while they might not know Java
- No need to install Java on your servers

Comment: For some reason, as of version 2.16.1 I find that a lot of Phing specific tasks for tools such as `phploc`, `phpcpd`, `phpdepend`, `phpcs` and `phpmd`, for example, don't seem to work and return exceptions. Also, it seems to have a problem finding these tools even if they are in the `$PATH` directories. I ended up having to rewrite tasks to use these tools in generic Ant buildfile syntax i.e. using the `exec` task to make them work with Phing. It almost defeated the purpose of using Phing. My build server was running PHP 7.2 if that matters.

Answer (score 9):

The main argument (*for me*) for using Phing when doing PHP development is

- staying inside the PHP Ecosystem.
- When using Phing on shared hosts, you can be sure it works when PHP works.
- And you can easily [extend Phing](http://phing.info/docs/guide/stable/chapters/ExtendingPhing.html) with your own task in PHP.
- And since it's a PHP tool you will [sometimes find it in other applications](http://phing.info/trac/wiki/Users/ProjectsUsingPhing) as well.